# regex to allow space if followed by character

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have an asp.net regularexpressionvalidator that I need to match on a textbox.  If there is any text, logically the rules are as follows:

The text must be at least three characters, after any trimming to remove spaces.
Characters allowed are a-zA-Z0-9-' /\&.

I'm having major pain trying to construct an expression that will allow a space as the thrid character only if there is a fourth non-space character.

Can anyone suggest an expression?  My last attempt was:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\.](([a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\.][a-zA-Z0-9-' /\\&\.])|([a-zA-Z0-9-' /\\&\.][a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\.]))[a-zA-Z0-9-' /\\&\.]{0,}$
```

but that does not match on 'a  a'.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be regexp? With your requirements on the string it should be easier to just prune the string and check it’s length or use the charseq-regexp on the space-pruned string.

Comment: This should be possible with lookahead or lookbehind but I don't know whether asp's regex flavor supports this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html (I clearly have no clue about this technology ;)).

Comment: Sorry, characters allowed include space, unless the string would reduce to less than three characters after trimming.

Comment: So the minimum would be two non-space characters, separated by two space characters, right?

Comment: @Kissaki this has to be used within a regularexpressionvalidator.  Trimming happens after the validation.

Comment: @Tim Minimum would be two non-space, seperated by a single space.

Comment: It would be much easier to trim the string first and then check length and allowed characters. Doing this in a single regex is not a good idea.

Comment: @Tim, I agree, but I can't do that within the framework I have available.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "trimming"? you mean removing leading and trailing spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, now this is all in one regex:

```
^\s*(?=[a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.-])([a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.\s-]{3,})(?<=\S)\s*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                      # Start of string
\s*                    # Optional leading whitespace, don't capture that.
(?=                    # Assert that...
 [a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.-]    # the next character is allowed and non-space
)
(                      # Match and capture...
 [a-zA-Z0-9'/\\&.\s-]{3,} # three or more allowed characters, including space
)
(?<=\S)                # Assert that the previous character is not a space
\s*                    # Optional trailing whitespace, don't capture that.
$                      # End of string
```

This matches

```
abc
aZ- &//
a  ab  abc   x
    aaa
a a
```

and doesn't match

```
aa
abc!
     a&
```

Comment: This seems to be perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: I have since discovered that look-behind is not supported by the javascript part of the validation.  I have still used this expression, but disalbled the client validation.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your allowed characters to be a-z and space for clarity, doesn't this do it?

`^ *[a-z][a-z ]+[a-z] *$`

Ignore spaces. Now a letter. Then some letters or spaces. Then a letter. Ignore more spaces.

The full thing becomes:

`^ *[a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\.][a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\. ]+[a-zA-Z0-9-'/\\&\.] *$`